# How to add a <hr> to the top of a <td> while keeping the content centered?

Tags: html, css

I tried to add a horizontal line inside a `<td>` tag to achieve :

[image: This is what I want]

but this is what I got :

[image: This is what I get]

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6qybn8w8/

Please note that I want this `<hr />` tag to appear in only few of the `<td>` and not all. Also, I cannot remove the padding for `<td>` as I need it to format content of other `<td>s`

Comment: Edited the jsfiddle link

Comment: Try to style this `<hr\>` in CSS. I'd start with `padding: 0;` and `margin: 0 auto;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do some thing like this.

```css
table {
  border: 3px solid #0D94D2;
}
table th,
td {
  padding: 4px 10px 4px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
table th {
  background-color: #0D94D2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.25em 0.25em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
table td {
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #B1DCEA;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
hr {
  position: relative;
  color: #0000FF;
  background-color: #0000FF;
  height: 0.75em;
  width: 118.9%;
  left: -6.5%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <th>
      Data
    </th>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <hr />
        <div>
          Some Gibber Gabber
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround for you to get the expected result without breaking your structure is by using positioning.

Well I've updated the fiddle so you can go through the changes, http://jsfiddle.net/6qybn8w8/2/

**HTML:**

```
<body>
   <table>
       <th>
           Data
       </th>
       <tr>
       <td>
           <hr />
           <div>
           Some Gibber Gabber
           </div>
       </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
table{
   border:3px solid #0D94D2;
}

table th,td{
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 5px; font-size: 12px;
}

table th{
    background-color:#0D94D2;text-align:center;padding:0.25em 0.25em;white-space:nowrap;
}
table td{
    width:auto;text-align:center;border-bottom: 1px solid #B1DCEA;white-space:nowrap;position:relative;
}

table td div{
    margin-top:10px;
}

hr{
    color: #0000FF;
    background-color: #0000FF;
    height: 0.75em;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:-10px;
    left:-1px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the height of `<hr>` as 0 and add `margin-top` to `5px` or whatever that you want.

```css
table{
   border:3px solid #0D94D2;
}

table th,td{
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 5px; font-size: 12px;
}

table th{
    background-color:#0D94D2;text-align:center;padding:0.25em 0.25em;white-space:nowrap;
}
table td{
    width:auto;text-align:center;border-bottom: 1px solid #B1DCEA;white-space:nowrap;
}

hr{
    height: 0em;
    border-top: 5px solid green;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <table>
       <th>
           Data
       </th>
       <tr>
       <td>
           <hr />
           <div>
           Some Gibber Gabber
           </div>
       </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/6qybn8w8/5/